# How to login with username/password using OAuth2 and microsoft login and HTTP request

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, active-directory

How to login with username/password (end-user credentials) using OAuth2 and Microsoft login

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{app-id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bapp-id%7D/oauth2/token)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft does not recommend passing username/password information for endusers. That is why they dont post guides for this. For security reason they want you to use the redirection to their login page. Use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize to get there.

However it is possible and very easy to do this using their oauth2 rest api.

Create an http request to

```
base url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token
{tenant-id} //obtained from AzureAD config section
```

Use the following request parameters in the body section

```
grant_type = password //read up on the other grant types, they are all useful, client_credentials and authorization_code
client_id = {client-id}//obtained from the application section in AzureAD
client_secret = {client-secret}//obtained from the application section in AzureAD
resource = https://graph.microsoft.com //there is also the api https://graph.windows.net, use the latest and best one
username = {enduser-username} //example rofler@domain.onmicrosoft.com
password = {enduser-password} //example Hs782f8a
```

A successful response should include the access_token and refresh_token

Tested in year 2016

Recommended links

- [Postman](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinyLbA7ubQAhXLlCwKHbpqBV4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fpostman%2Ffhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop&usg=AFQjCNEKwgqPDcgrMAsS6iZ8PUYhTzB58A&sig2=3N2MJILCR5FqBlyDDBe4Yg)
- [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview)
- [Windows Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)

Comment: Is this still not a recommended approach?, Is there a guide on how to use just Client_ID and Client Secret and lock down access to only one site collection?

Comment: Hi @Deepak 


Yes, Client ID and Client Secret authentication (and all the various HTTP Request-based authentication methods) are located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret


The one in the accepted answer above is called the Resource Owner Provided Credentials (ROPC), and the Microsoft documentation on that one can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc