# Microsoft login from oauth2 issue

Tags: azure, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, axios

I have a React app using `axios` library for handling request. So following the next post:

[How to login with username/password using OAuth2 and microsoft login and HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058048/how-to-login-with-username-password-using-oauth2-and-microsoft-login-and-http-re)

I could perform the action on Postman.

Then I set up the axios library to perform the `POST`

```
const dataForBody = `${'grant_type=password&' +
      'username='}${encodeURI(userName)}&` +
      `password=${encodeURI(userPassword)}&` +
      `client_id=${encodeURI(clientID)}&` +
      `resource=${encodeURI('https://graph.microsoft.com')}&` +
      `client_secret=${encodeURI(clientSecret)}`;
const messageHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token',
  headers: messageHeaders,
  data: dataForBody,
})
  .then((response) => {

  });
```

but I get the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I tried adding:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
```

to the headers, but it did not work.

So adding `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *​​​` chrome extension fixed my problem.

The thing is, my app is to be published on azure, so I tested the request on other web browsers and it did not work. So I don't want my users to install the extension.

Is there something wrong with my request? Why postman can do it without setting up headers?

Is there any other approach to achieve it?

PS: I read about using `adal.js` but I dont want to use the login screen from microsoft, because I know user and pass for the app, and I want to avoid manual login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you face is due to you trying to call the token endpoint via AJAX, which it won't accept due to the CORS header missing. You can't add it, it's missing from the response from Azure AD.

What you need to do is instead of getting the access token from the token endpoint, you must use the OAuth Implicit Grant Flow. This flow allows you to get the tokens directly in the authorization stage, and is especially designed for JavaScript-based apps. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant.

What this means is that you can't use the Password Grant Flow as you are doing now, unless you make the calls from your backend instead of the frontend.

Comment: It still requires redirecting the user to the login page to get the access token. Do you have any sample code that is doing without redirection?

Comment: I am making a POST call to https://login.microsoftonline.com but getting the CORS issue in every browser but POSTMAN is working fine.

Comment: Yes, because AAD will not allow you to make the call. Postman does not care about CORS so it makes the call. CORS is just an agreement that browsers implement where they will first ask if it's okay to make the call to another origin. Postman does not ask.

Comment: So, how can I resolve this issue? Is there any way to implement something in my JS to get rid of this issue?

Comment: No. CORS is a server feature. And you do not control the server in this case.

Comment: I have observed one more thing, I just created a console application in C# and through HTTPClinet getting access token and it is giving me without any issue. However, the issue is only on JS side.

Comment: Yes, because browsers implement CORS checking. Your C# client is the same as Postman, it doesn't care about CORS. Browsers care about it.