# How pass login.microsoftonline.com authentication?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a program that works with an external (foreign) site and it saves me a lot of time. She performed basic username and password authentication by submitting an httpPOST request and did some useful chore. Now their site has switched to azure, and authentication has changed. I was given a new login, but I don't understand how I can rewrite my program.

[image]

The screenshot is in Cyrillic, but you can easily recognize authentication via login.microsoftonline.com
Is there a ready-made solution that allows you to pass this authentication, of course, if you have a valid username and password?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
I found the official MS repository (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) but I get infinite wait when submitting a request. I've tried every possible type of request, but sending a request or waiting for a response takes forever.

Comment: Did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41058049/4836581
Also you can try adding &login_hint=Zvi@gmail.com to the URL - for username only.